# Finding which variable causes outlier in linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression, outliers, anomaly-detection, ransac

I have two sets of variables in 'x' and 'y'. I am regressing 'y' on 'x' with robust linear regression methods - in particular, RANSAC. My objective is to extract outliers, which RANSAC does quite conveniently. However, I also want to know whether it was the 'x' or the 'y' component that caused it to be an outlier, i.e., figure out which dimension caused the abnormality? Can anybody kindly suggest ideas I could use to this end?

Comment: AFAIK ransac simply gets the line of best fit among your data points by randomly selecting 2 points until best fit is achieved or iterations end. A naive way would be to take the outliers determined by ransac and evaluate the distance between the outlier x-y coordinates and the line determined by ransac.